# Close an injected iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script that runs from my chrome extension.
this script injects an `iframe` to the body of the current page.
i want to have the possibility to close the `iframe` from within the `iframe`.
how do i do this?
when i searched this issue on the web, almost each solution uses the `window.parent.document` property which for some reason is undefined in my case. any ideas?

**EDIT - Code Sample:**

in the HTML of the `iframe`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function frameClose() {
            var windowFrames = window.parent.frames;
            for (var i = 0; i < windowFrames.length; i++) {
                var aFrame = windowFrames[i];
                if (aFrame.name == 'myFrame') {
                    alert('in frame');
                    // WHAT TO DO HERE?
                    // window.parent.document is undefined
                    // aFrame.parentNode.removeChild(aFrame); - THIS DOES NOT WORK ALSO
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

this is how i inject the `iframe`:

*Extension.js*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file : "/js/PushIFrame.js"
    }, function() {
        if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
        }
    });
});
```

and in *PushIFrame.js* i have:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "pushFrame",
    source: pushIframe(document)
});

function pushIframe(document) {
    var existingFrame = document.getElementById('bmarkFrame');
    if (existingFrame == null) {
        var temp = document.createElement('iframe');
        temp.id = 'myFrame';
        temp.name = 'myFrame';
        temp.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
        temp.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');
        temp.style.border = 'none';
        temp.style.height = '100%';
        temp.style.width = '100%';
        temp.style.position = 'fixed';
        temp.style.zIndex = 99999999;
        temp.style.top = 0;
        temp.style.left = 0;
        temp.style.display = 'block';
        temp.src = 'https://www.mysite.com/';

        document.body.appendChild(temp);
    }
    else {
        existingFrame.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: window.parent.document being undefined is strange. How are you injecting the Iframe?

Comment: Please put some context to your issue: if window.parent.document is undefined we need to know why. Show us some code please.

Comment: in my extension i have a chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener. when my extension is clicked i have chrome.tabs.executeScript which creates the iframe and sets its src attribute. i need from within the html of the iframe to close it so i have a function that goes over all the frames (window.parent.frames). when i get to my frame, i tried to remove it from the window.parent.document but its undefined.

Comment: Use `parent.postMessage` from the iframe to notify the content script which in turn closes the frame.

Comment: @RobW - Can you please post a code sample to your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the content script (say `PushIframe.js`) bind a `message` event to the main frame. Then, whenever you want to hide the iframe, call [`parent.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to notify the main frame. This message is received by the content script, from where you can hide the frame (as defined in your function `pushIframe`).

```
// PushIframe.js:
addEventListener('message', function(ev) {
    if (ev.data === 'closeIframe') {
        pushIframe(document); // Your code
    }
});

// Iframe:
<script>
function frameClose() {
    parent.postMessage('closeIframe', '*');
}
</script>
```